# Como posicionar elementos html con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo una página para agregar productos a una factura:

- Tiene una parte para filtrar por nombre o codigo.
- Otra parte para ordenamiento por categoría o precio.
- Por ultimo un
  edit no editable donde se pone el nombre de producto al hacer clik en
  una fila, y que, junto a la cantidad introducida en otro edit se
  procesan al hacer click en agregar. Todo esto dentro de un formulario
  para dicho fin.

El caso es que no logro ubicar los elementos y quería saber una técnica correcta para hacerlo.

```html
<form>
<p>FILTRO</p>
  <script src="includes/js/busqProducto.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">COD</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" placeholder="Codigo Articulo"/>
    </div>



    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">NOMBRE</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Articulo"/>
   
  </div>
 


<p>ORDENAMIENTO</p>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="margin: 20px 0 0 10px;">
    
    
      <input type="checkbox" id="marca"/>
      <label>NOMBRE</label>
      <select id="mySelect" data-show-icon="true">
       <option>  ASC</option>
       <option>  DESC</option>
</select>

    
      <input type="checkbox"id="categoria"/>
      <label>PRECIO</label>
      <select id="mySelect" data-show-icon="true">
       <option>  ASC</option>
       <option>  DESC</option>
</select>
   
  </div>


</form>
<form style="position:relative;width: 100%;">
    <div class="col-sm-8"  >
      <input type="text" disabled="true" class="form-control" id="nombreselec" placeholder="Nombre Articulo"/>
  </div> 

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CANTIDAD" placeholder="CANT"/>

  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Agregar
  </button>
</div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Terminado
  </button>
</div>
</form>
<table id="resultado">
<thead>
<tr> <th>COD.:</th> <th>DESCRIPCION</th> <th>MARCA</th>
            <th>CATEGORIA</th> <th>P/U</th><th>+</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Aqui una imagen actual:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea es alinear el nombre y la cantidad a los dos botones.
Espero su ayuda

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo echar un vistazo al [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) de Bootstrap. Si estás trabajando con tablas y formularios, Bootstrap tiene clases ya definidas para estos elementos con los que podrías trabajar: [Formularios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) - [Tablas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) .

Comment: Gracias,le hechare un vistazo

Answer (score 3):

En esta parte tienes mal el grid, en total la suma de sus columnas tiene que dar 12 y aqui tienes 14 "8+2+2+2=14"

```
<form style="position:relative;width: 100%;">
    <div class="col-sm-8"  >
      <input type="text" disabled="true" class="form-control" id="nombreselec" placeholder="Nombre Articulo"/>
  </div> 

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CANTIDAD" placeholder="CANT"/>

  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Agregar
  </button>
</div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Terminado
  </button>
</div>
</form>
```

La forma correcta seria disminuyendo el valor a una columna en su clase asi (6+2+2+2=12):

```
<form style="position:relative;width: 100%;">
    <div class="col-sm-6"  >
      <input type="text" disabled="true" class="form-control" id="nombreselec" placeholder="Nombre Articulo"/>
  </div> 

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CANTIDAD" placeholder="CANT"/>

  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Agregar
  </button>
</div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Terminado
  </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias..la verdad no sabia que la suma tenia que dar 12.

Answer (score 0):

Además de que la suma de las columnas deben dar 12 tienes que crear div de clases row-fluid, al igual que las tablas tienen filas y columnas nuestra página también las tiene, en el caso de las columnas como anteriormente se indicó es igual a 12 por fila, la clase que se asigna es col-md-x donde el valor de en medio o para este ejemplo "me" corresponde a medium, osea será una columna de tamaño mediano que ocupe x columnas, el tamaño si no estoy equivocado se usa para adaptar el contenido a los diferentes dispositivos, bootstrap también tiene clases responsives que están creadas para eso, el contenido se ajusta al tamaño del navegador/pantalla, te recomiendo ir a la página de bootstrap y buscar el contenido correspondiente , allí podrás ver ejemplos didácticos que te ayudarán mucho